# spring custom logout filter to perform some action before logs out?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.0. I just need to perform some logic before user logs out.

Is it possible to achieve that by overriding the `LogoutFilter` class of Spring Security?

Answer (score 3):

There a bunch of ways to do that. I'll tell you the two that I would consider.

1) Creating my own filter that does the things that I need. The key point here is that if you create a filter, you must also tell Spring Security to put it into the "filter chain", the chain of filters your requests go through in order to do auth* stuff. [Check this documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-custom-filters) to know how to insert your filters in the right spot in more details, but it will look something like

```
<http>
    <custom-filter before="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="cleanupFilter" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="cleanupFilter" class="com.CleanupFilter"/>
```

Remember that by sublassing LogoutFilter you are still creating a custom filter, so same thing apply.

2) If my custom logic can be executed not strictly before the user logs out but also slight after, consider using [`SecurityContextLogoutHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html) (check docs at section B.1.13) that will give you an hook point to perform custom logic when the users successfully logs out.

```
<http>
    <logout success-handler-ref="myLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
</http>
```