# how to perform operation just before logout in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

First of all this is not a duplicate question i checked answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112972/spring-security-customize-logout-handler)! and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940017/spring-custom-logout-filter-to-perform-some-action-before-logs-out)! but couldnt get it to work.

Also i want to perform it just before logout so can not use logoutSuccessHandler.

So i need to create a custom LOGOUT_FILTER , with which i am really having hard time getting it to work.

here is my spring-security xml in which i tried two methods
first was :-

```
 <custom-filter ref="logoutFilter" position="LOGOUT_FILTER" />

<beans:bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
<beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="/logoutSuccess" />
<beans:constructor-arg index="1">
    <beans:list>
        <beans:bean id="securityContextLogoutHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
    <beans:bean id="myLogoutHandler" class="com.fe.cms.listener.SimpleLogoutHandler" />
    </beans:list>
</beans:constructor-arg>
<beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/logout" />
</beans:bean>
```

but this gives me error

```
Configuration problem: Security namespace does not support decoration of element [custom-filter]
```

then i tried..

```
<beans:bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="/logout" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1">
        <beans:ref bean="securityContextLogoutHandler" />
        <beans:ref bean="myLogoutHandler" />
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/logout" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="securityContextLogoutHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />

<beans:bean id="myLogoutHandler" class="com.fe.cms.listener.SimpleLogoutHandler" />

<http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationManger">
    <custom-filter ref="logoutFilter" position="LOGOUT_FILTER" />
</http>
```

but this gives me error :-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#48' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [48]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#48': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [6]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#181': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

Please can anyone tell where am i doing wrong ..
i will post full xml files if needed

Comment: Describe what you want also I doubt you need a custom logout filter as it probably can be done with a `LogoutHandler` which is added to the chain of other `LogoutHandler`s. But as you don't tell what you want to achieve (functionally) it is hard to tell.

Comment: @M.Deinum i actually want to perform some operation on session data when session is about to destroy.. hope it is clear now

Comment: Then simply write an `ApplicationListener` that listens for `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent`s. Also register the `HttpSessionEventPublisher` to your web.xml. This way you will also be able to process sessions that time-out instead of only regular logout.

Comment: But i think then my listener will run after Session is Destroyed and then i will not be able to access session anymore..correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You are wrong... It will be called DURING session destruction... See my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your clarification what you want is to get access the to session and perform some logic. Instead of hacking around with a custom `LogoutFilter` simply write an `ApplicationListener` that listens to [`HttpSessionDestroyedEvent`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/session/HttpSessionDestroyedEvent.html)s.

```
@Component
public class SessionListener implements ApplicationListener<HttpSessionDestroyedEvent> {

    public void onApplicationEvent(HttpSessionDestroyedEvent evt) {
        HttpSession session = evt.getSession();
        // Your logic here
    }
}
```

To be able re receive events make sure that you register the [`HttpSessionEventPublisher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/session/HttpSessionEventPublisher.html) in your web.xml.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Main advantage of this solution is that you will also be able to process sessions that timeout and not only regular logouts.

Comment: i tried this method and it resulted in the same way like interceptor..logout method of `SecurityContextLogoutHandler` is called even before the Listener which already destroys the session....

Comment: No it isn't as the session is still there because it is called **during** the destruction. Parameters and security contexts are still there. Also make sure you registered the listener (else it won't work). What is it that you want to do with the session anyway?

Comment: yes i registered it and it is getting called fine .. i am having a session scoped bean and i put some data on bean when user logs in and just want to perform some operation on that data when user logs out

Comment: And the problem you have is? If it is a session scoped bean as define din Spring then simply inject it into your listener...

Comment: Gave it a try again and it worked this time .. think i missed something last time .. thanks a lot @M. Deinum for simple and elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to execute some operation just before logout I suppose Spring *interceptors* can help you.

You could implement a class like this:

```
public class JustBeforeLogoutInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        boolean res = super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
        //
        // your code...
        //
        return res;
    }
}
```

Then you need to configure the interceptor:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/logout" />
        <bean class="your.app.JustBeforeLogoutInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

This should work. Take a try.

Comment: This seems a better solution :)

Comment: Thanks @davioooh but logout method of `SecurityContextLogoutHandler` is called even before the interceptor .. so by the time it reaches the interceptor the session is actually already destroyed..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extend current LogoutFilter and execute your custom logic before calling super class' doFilter method.

Like this

```
public class CustomLogoutFilter extends LogoutFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        if (requiresLogout(request, response)) {
           // IMPLEMENT YOUR CUSTOM LOGIC HERE

            super.doFilter(req, res, chain);

            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Then you have to replace default LogoutFilter with your CustomLogoutFilter

```
<http>
    <custom-filter position="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="customLogoutFilter" />
</http>

<bean id="customLogutFilter" class="example.CustomLogoutFilter">
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/logout" />
    <!-- Put other needed properties here-->
</bean>
```

Comment: thats what i have done if you see my question .. created a logout handler `myLogoutHandler` and i am facing an error.

Comment: In your question you simply override default filter with default filter implementatin with different properties. What I suggest was to implement your own LogoutFilter based on default logout filter implementation. The error you facing weird and hints a namespace problem which is probably a syntax problem in your XML configuration. Can you please add your XML configuration in your question. // Additionally you can try the solution of davioooh it seems really better.