# Setting up own security in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication

I have studied plenty tutorials and pages about Spring Boot Security. But none of them answered my questions. And here they are:

I´m building web app in Spring Boot. And I need to authenticate users via classic session (username, password). But as I know a lot of things are predefined in Spring Boot. And I want to change few things.

1) The only page which DO NOT NEED authentication is **/**. Here is also login form. Rest of pages MUST BE authenticated. So I do not want to use default URL **/login**. And what I have to write into form´s action?

2) I also need need unauthenticated routes for static resources. They are located: **src/main/resource/static/css**

3) Is there a way to edit logout? Like to add a code during logout action?

Can you show me how **configure** method of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter should look like? I have already tried a lot of configurations, but they didnt work.

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Can you share what you tried? So, we can help you based on that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to have a look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login) tutorial for a specific login and logout page.

With antmatchers you can also define that your static content is not secured.See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916894/serving-static-web-resources-in-spring-boot-spring-security-application)

For adding logic between spring defined processes like logout you should have a look at the spring filter pipelines especially the Logoutfiler. This was already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940017/spring-custom-logout-filter-to-perform-some-action-before-logs-out)

It would also be an easy way to set the logout url to a rest endpoint, execute the action you want an then redirect to the auth service. In my opion the filter way is the better solution and cleaner.

I hope this helps to get on track. cheers